# Pivot query where the pivot results can be date filtered with two seperate dates?

Tags: sql, pivot

Here is my query below:

```
select employid,deprtmnt,jobtitle,[H-RT],[H-OT]
from 
(                  
 SELECT employid,deprtmnt,jobtitle,chekdate,UNTSTOPY,Category                  
 FROM 
 (                  
   SELECT employid,deprtmnt,jobtitle,chekdate,UNTSTOPY,payrolcd as     category              
   FROM [upr30300]    
   where DEPRTMNT like '600%'          
 ) t                  
 where chekdate = '2012-03-09' and Category in ('H-RT','H-OT')                  
) d             
PIVOT
(
  SUM(UNTSTOPY) 
  FOR Category IN ([H-RT],[H-OT])
)p
```

The result shows columns including the two pivoted(H-RT and H-OT). I can filter by chekdate and get the results for the filter but am trying to figure out how to get two EXTRA columns showing H-RT, H-OT which would show the filtered chekdate plus 14 days.

I was trying to work with a dateadd function but cannot figure out how to get 1 result set that includes....H-RT(period1),H-OT(period1),H-RT(period2),H-OT(period2)...would anyone have a direction or idea of how to get this done?

Thank you in advance!

Here is the sample data:

```
EMPLOYID    DEPRTMNT    JOBTITLE    H-RT    H-OT
ABC123          600-20  CA      77.78000    7.47000
ABC124          600-80  CSA     55.65000    0.58000
ABC125          600-70  RAA     77.68000    0.03000
```

Here is desired data:

```
EMPLOYID    DEPRTMNT    JOBTITLE    H-RT1   H-OT1      H-RT2      H-OT2
ABC123          600-20  CA      77.78000    7.47000    80.00      12.00
ABC124          600-80  CSA     55.65000    0.58000    74.00      16.00
ABC125          600-70  RAA     77.68000    0.03000    48.00       2.00
```

THe desired data columns H-RT1,H-OT1 is where chekdate = '2012-03-09' and columns H-RT2,H-OT2 would be where chekdate = '2012-03-09' + 14 days.

Comment: can you post some sample data from your table and then the desired result?

Comment: sorry for the way it looks...I'm not sure how to make my sample data show aligned correctly.

Comment: When you say `chekdate = '2012-03-09' + 14 days`, does it mean `chekdate = '2012-03-23'` or `chekdate BETWEEN '2012-03-09' AND '2012-03-23'`?

Comment: It should be between since there would be checks issued after the first date for missed employees. Thank you.

Comment: What you added was a sample *output* of your query. It's a useful piece of information, but it would be really great if you posted a sample of *source data* (preferably one matching the posted output).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something similar to this:

```
select employid,
  deprtmnt,
  jobtitle,
  [H-RT_1],
  [H-OT_1], 
  [H-RT_2],
  [H-OT_2]
from 
(                  
 SELECT employid,
    deprtmnt,
    jobtitle,
    chekdate,
    UNTSTOPY,
    Category,
    case when chekdate = '2012-03-09' then Category+'_1' 
      when chekdate = dateadd(d, 14, '2012-03-09') then Category+'_2' end period
 FROM 
 (                  
   SELECT employid,
     deprtmnt,
     jobtitle,
     chekdate,
     UNTSTOPY,
     payrolcd as category              
   FROM [upr30300]    
   where DEPRTMNT like '600%'
 ) t                  
 where (chekdate = '2012-03-09' or chekdate = dateadd(d, 14, '2012-03-09'))
    and Category in ('H-RT','H-OT')                  
) d             
PIVOT
(
  SUM(UNTSTOPY) 
  FOR Category IN ([H-RT_1],[H-OT_1], [H-RT_2],[H-OT_2])
)p
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response bluefeet....but I am receiving null values for the RT and OT columns plus I'm receiving multiple records for each employee...hmmm

Comment: @JaeChang can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some data from your main table `[upr30300]`?

Comment: Because of the `chekdate` column in the pre-pivot dataset, the two pairs of pivoted columns won't be placed on the same row. To me, `chekdate` doesn't really make sense in the output, but if it's definitely needed there, I would probably just use `'2012-03-09' as chekdate` instead of pulling the actual column.

Comment: @AndriyM you are most likely right.  The entire query can likely be refactored. I wish we had a full sample of data from the table, that would make it easier. :)

Comment: As far as posting sample data...is it supposed to be four spaces prior to posting to have it aligned correctly? I apologize for the messiness and thank you all for your help!

Comment: @JaeChang you should create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the table and then some sample data.

Comment: I did post some sample data from upr30300 but needed "peer approval" or something like that. It looks like it's gone now. I will try to get the sample data through sql fiddle. Thank you bluefeet.

Comment: @JaeChang: It's best to edit your *own* posts under your *own* account. That way your edits are applied immediately, without the intermediate review stage. And why would you use more than one account, anyway?